# json did not give me compete Format ,

Tags: android, json

i am making Json , but i does not make correct format 
it give me only fist property of User  and last property item , not give me complete json ..
advance thanks ..
my code is

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

        try {
            JSONObject subJson = new JSONObject();
            //JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

            subJson.put("saleManId", LogIn.UserId);
            subJson.put("customerId", LogIn.CustomerId);

            json.put("User", subJson);

            for (int i = 0; i < LogIn.subValues.length; i++) {
                JSONObject subSubObj = new JSONObject();

                for (int j = 0; j < LogIn.subValues[i].length; j++) {
                    if (LogIn.subValues[i][j] > 0) {

                        JSONObject item = new JSONObject();

                        item.put("itemID", LogIn.subIds[i][j]);
                        item.put("qty", LogIn.subValues[i][j]);

                        subSubObj.put("item", item);

                    }

                }


                if(subSubObj.length()>0)
                {
                    json.put("orderDetail", subSubObj);
                    Log.d("json", json.toString());
                }


            }
            Log.d("jsonnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn", json.toString());

        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

their is 30 to 35 item in Array ,but it give me only this

```
{"orderDetail":{"item":{"qty":1,"itemID":"60"}},"User":{"customerId":"460","saleManId":"1"}}
```

Comment: You need a JSONArray somewhere if you want a collection of objects

Comment: JSONArray take only value but i need key also ..

Comment: a jsonobject can have only one value for a given key ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it ... :) thanks to all ...

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

        try {
            JSONObject subJson = new JSONObject();
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

            subJson.put("saleManId", LogIn.UserId);
            subJson.put("customerId", LogIn.CustomerId);

            json.put("User", subJson);

            for (int i = 0; i < LogIn.subValues.length; i++) {



                for (int j = 0; j < LogIn.subValues[i].length; j++) {
                    if (LogIn.subValues[i][j] > 0) {

                        JSONObject subSubObj = new JSONObject();
                        JSONObject item = new JSONObject();

                        item.put("itemID", LogIn.subIds[i][j]);
                        item.put("qty", LogIn.subValues[i][j]);

                        subSubObj.put("item", item);

                        jsonArray.put(subSubObj);

                    }

                }


            }

            json.put("orderDetail", jsonArray);
            Log.d("jsonnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn", json.toString());

        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
         sendString = json.toString();
```

out put result is ..

```
{"orderDetail":[
{"item":{"qty":1,"itemID":"4"}},
{"item":{"qty":1,"itemID":"14"}},
{"item":{"qty":1,"itemID":"28"}},
{"item":{"qty":1,"itemID":"59"}},
{"item":{"qty":1,"itemID":"60"}},
{"item":{"qty":1,"itemID":"62"}},
{"item":{"qty":1,"itemID":"24"}},
{"item":{"qty":1,"itemID":"36"}},
{"item":{"qty":1,"itemID":"51"}}],
"User":{"customerId":"414","saleManId":"1"}}
```